# Datagrip with postgres replace returned parameters in stored functions

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

DataGrip replaces "RETURNS TABLE(val1 type1, val2 type2, ...)" on "RETURNS set" in stored functions.

But when I called in psql

`\ef <functionname>`

is shows "RETURNS TABLE.."

Is that a bug or feature of DataGrip? 
It's very uncomfortable to edit functions with that type of return, `cause postgresql couldn't find  variables, which delared in "RETURNS TABLE(val1 type1, val2 type2, ...)".

Comment: Hello! It will be fixed in 2016.2 (release this month)

Comment: Check the new version